# Bash: displaying wc with three digit output?

Tags: bash, ls, wc

conducting a word count of a directory.

ls | wc -l

if output is "17", I would like the output to display as "017".

I have played with | printf   with little luck.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls | wc -l` will tell you how many lines it encountered [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which may not be the same as the number of (non-dot) filenames in the directory. What if a filename has a newline? One reliable way to get the number of files in a directory is

```
x=(*)
printf '%03d\n' "${#x[@]}"
```

But that will only work with a shell that supports arrays. If you want a POSIX compatible approach, use a shell function:

```
countargs() { printf '%03d\n' $#; }
countargs *
```

This works because when a glob expands the shell maintains the words in each member of the glob expansion, regardless of the characters in the filename. But when you pipe a filename the command on the other side of the pipe can't tell it's anything other than a normal string, so it can't do any special handling.

Comment: This worked as well as the one above, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is the way to go to format numbers:

```
printf "There were %03d files\n" "$(ls | wc -l)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud use sed.

```
ls | wc -l | sed 's/^17$/017/'
```

And this applies to all the two digit numbers.

```
ls | wc -l | sed '/^[0-9][0-9]$/s/.*/0&/'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  the second suggestion is close, the files in this dir can range from 5 - 150. so I played with your suggestion and currently:  ls | wc -l | sed '/^[0-999]$/s/.*/00&/'    this gives me three digit output if the count is 9 or less and 100+  but 2 digits still return as two digits.